# What category is because?

Tags: parts-of-speech

sorry if this seems really basic!

I am stuck on what to name 'because' in the syntax tree I am drawing, which is for the sentence:
'The boy gave Alice a present because he likes her'.

I initially thought that it would be a CP but also considered that like 'and' it would be a conjunction.

Can some please clarify for me?
Much thanks!

Comment: I do not really see this as a request to *draw* a syntax tree, rather one how to syntactically classify the *beacuse* in this context. I am sure there were whole monographs written on the topic. Neither it is a grammar usage question. Both stated reasons for putting it on hold seem not to apply.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on who you ask. 'Because' is not in the same syntactic category as 'and', as they show different behaviour:

> (1) a. I am looking for her because she is missing.
>
> b. She is missing and her boyfriend is dead.
>
> (2) a. Because she is missing, I am looking for her.
>
> b. *And her boyfriend is dead, she is missing.

More traditional approaches categorise 'because' as a **subordinating conjunction** in the same category as *since*, *as*, *if*, *as long as*, *although*, etc., as opposed to coordinating conjunctions like *and*, *or* and *but*. More modern approaches subsume the category of subordinating conjunctions under **prepositions** instead. A prominent grammar that advocates the preposition view is the Huddleston and Pullum grammar. Pullum also makes the cause that *because* is a preposition [here](http://languagelog.ldc.upenn.edu/nll/?p=9494). The basic idea is that a preposition may subcategorise for a full clause, which is what 'because' can do.